# Auto Refreshing Filter Excel for Dynamic Graph Ranges

Tags: excel, filter, lookup

I am trying to graph a set of data for visual analysis.

The data contains around 50 rows of lookups, but does not necessarily populate all rows. i.e. Selecting Factor A gives me 20 rows of data, and 30 rows of zeroes.

As the tab is currently designed for me to be able to cycle between Factors to graph them instead of creating an individual tab per factor, this graph needs to switch between graphing anywhere between 0-50 lines excluding the blanks where necessary.

I have used a filter to take out all the zeroes allowing the graph range to be "dynamic", but the filter isn't refreshing correctly when I select a different Factor (changing the # of rows).

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

End Sub
```

found in previous threads does not seem to refresh the filter for me.

TLDR version; 
How do I force Excel to always filter a particular criteria (i.e. Remove/Hide zeroes) when the column values change?

Comment: Are you talking about value change due to a formula or actual value change because you pasted new values into the column? The former does not trigger the Worksheet_Change event macro. The latter does.

Comment: It would be a value change from a drop-down list created using "Data validation"

Comment: Would _calculate be more appropriate perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This modification works for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target.Parent
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            'this next line isn't absolutely necessary
            'but it doesn't hurt anything and could be necessary later
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
        End If
    End With
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

Make sure you haven't crashed out event handling and left it in a False state by running `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx).